# No Suggestion for <artifactId> on Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, intellij-idea

First of all, I apologize for my english. When I try to create a .spring MVC project, I first created a maven project. Then, in pom.xml, nothing happens to my  section. Below are the pom.xml and the project settings showing the mavel's fault.
[image: Maven Error on Project Structure]

[image: Pom.xml]

- **SOLVED**

Just update maven repository.Settings-> Build, Execution... -> Builds Tools -> Maven -> repositories.

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-165502 could be related, please report bugs to YouTrack and attach [the logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085).

Comment: This is last version intellij idea ultimate version.Linked with screenshots that you have sent along with you.

Comment: Comment from the issue posted above: Did you update/scan your mvn repositories? Settings-> Build, Execution... -> Builds Tools -> Maven -> repositories  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-165502#comment=27-1927592'

Comment: Ty @meistermeier . Solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update/scan your repositories before you can use the auto-completion in the pom files.

Open `Settings` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Build Tools` -> `Maven` -> `Repositories`, select the repository you want to update and hit the `Update` button.

[image: repository-update-dialog]

(transferred comment to an answer to let others find it)